# oembed_cache SPAM problem

Tags: phpmyadmin, oembed, spam

I recently found hundreds of posts with post_type oembed_cache while looking into my database. Many of them appear to be spam. I can't for the life of me figure out how there are being injected into my database. Here is a picture from phpmyadmin [LINK](https://www.iwdhosting.ca/db-spam.png). Is anyone else having this issue? Can anyone offer any insight? How do I clean this up and more importantly how do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: WordPress creates these itself when you have a link on the page where the target URL has an oembed link tag in its header. So it sounds like you have pages on your site with spam links on them. At first glance there's no obvious way to track these back to the URLs they came from, as WordPress stores them by MD5 cache.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much for your reply. It helped me figure out what's going on.

I get a far bit of spam submissions via my contact form, these spam submissions include URLs. Although they are being flagged as spam and filtered out, WordPress still creates an oembed_cache entry in the database for them.

I have verified I do not have any actual spam links on my website, so in my case they are relatively harmless.

It would appear that I can occasional remove the bogus entries from my database or I can use the Disable Embeds plugin.

Cheers.